# OO JavaScript circumventing .call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhdvd/2/)

In the show function the JavaScript call method is used to make `this` refer to the `container` variable in my contactForm object.  I think, I'm not too sure about the magic that makes this work.  Can someone elucidate why this does work, and what a good alternative might be?

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var contactForm = {
                container: $('#contact'),
                config: {
                    effect: 'slideToggle',
                    speed: 400
                },
                /*******************/
                init: function (config) {
                    $.extend(this.config, config);
                    $('<button>').text('Contact me')
                                 .attr('type', 'button')
                                 .insertAfter('#firstArticle')
                                 .on('click', this.show);
                   //currently only logic on the close button
                },
                /*******************/
                show: function () {
                    //using variable names to shorten up
                    var cf = contactForm,
                        container = cf.container,
                        config = cf.config;
                    if (container.is(':hidden')) {
                        cf.close.call(container);
                        container[config.effect](config.speed);
                    }
                },
                /*******************/
                close: function () {
                    var self = $(this);
                    if (self.find('span.close').length) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $('<span>').addClass('close')
                               .text('close')
                               .prependTo(this)
                               .on('click', function () {
                                   //self= span
                                   self[contactForm.config.effect](500)
                               });
                }
            };


            contactForm.init();

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic at all; that's just how `call` works.  `call` lets you call a JavaScript function and manually specify the `this` value therein, followed by all of the parameters, listed out individually.

So

```
cf.close.call(container);
```

calls `cf.close` with the `this` value set to `container`.  Hypothetically, this

```
cf.close.call(container, 1, 'b');
```

would do the same thing, except *also* pass in 1 and 'b' as parameters.

Call is very, very similar to `apply`, with the difference being that apply takes all parameters as an array, rather than being listed out individually.  So the (hypothetical) second example would be the same as

```
cf.close.apply(container, [1, 'b']);
```

This can be incredibly useful when you want to call another function, set the this value, and wholesale pass all of the current function's arguments along for the ride.  Ie

```
someFunction.apply(thisValue, arguments);
```

Comment: I did not know that you could pass multiple parameters to `call`, thanks for the heads up.